# Как сконвертировать html-строку в картинку или canvas для отображения?

Tags: javascript

Хочу в карточках для превью отображать верстку в виде картинки или canvas, я пробовал использовать dom-to-image, html-to-image, html2canvas, но все эти библиотеки требуют работы с реальным dom.

Comment: А как вы себе представляете рендер html без привязки к реальному dom?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, никак не представляю, если бы я знал, я бы не задал вопрос в том виде, в котором он знал. Я и спрашиваю, есть ли возможность преобразовать html строку в изображение.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, на сервере же как-то преобразуют. Там DOM'a нет.

Comment: Кто на сервере преобразует? Где? Когда? По вопросу - что бы преобразовать html в изображение, для этого этот html нужно обработать и отрендерить, этим заниается движок, который есть в браузерах. Собственно, вам нужен реальный dom.

Comment: node-html-to-image

Comment: *It uses puppeteer in headless mode to achieve it.* - то есть использует браузерный движок.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, вы верно меня неправильно поняли: инструменты выше рендерят только элементы, полученные с дом. Они не смогут срендерить строку.

Comment: Никто и ничто не может срендерить строку. Что бы срендерить строку, надо ее превратить в dom или как-то по другому обработать.

Comment: Кстати, из вопроса не понятно, где вы хотите рендерить - в браузере или на node.js?